# Convert po box javascript regex to c# regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I saw the following javascript regex on a stack overflow article and I would like to convert it to C#:

```
var poBox = /^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)/i;
```

I've tried removing the / at the beginning and end which I believe is used to denote a string literal and I also removed /i at the end which seems to be for case insensitivity but I still seem to be missing other conversions here.

The original stack overflow article is here:
[PO Box Regular Expression Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680050/po-box-regular-expression-validation)

Can anyone tell me what else I'm missing here?  Not super familiar with regular expressions and I'm struggling a bit here.

### Edit:

Here is the modified c# code with the above notes:

```
public const string PoBoxRegex = @"^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)";

public static bool IsPoBox(string addressToCheck)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressToCheck))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (Regex.IsMatch(addressToCheck, PoBoxRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would help if you showed the c# you have so far and what the syntax error you get is.

Comment: Are you at least using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` if you removed `/i`? You also should  use a verbatim string literal - `@"pattern"`, and replace ``\/`` with `/`

Comment: The pattern should work well in C#. If you write it correctly.

Comment: @Wobbles, Honestly the c# was so simple I didn't think it was necessary or essential to post this.  I have posted it anyway.  It wasn't a syntax error.  It's the fact the regex doesn't recognize the inputs it says it should in the original stack overflow post

Comment: Yes, but we need to check for syntax, typos, any any number of other things that could cause the expression to fail in c#. Also you do not indicate what the actual issue is, does it toss an exception, does it not find a match? if the latter can you provide a sample string to test it against as is suggested by [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew After changing `\/` with `/` that seemed to resolve the issue.  If you paste the full converted expression below as the answer I will accept it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is an `/i` modifier, you need to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. All `\/` should be written as `/` as the forward slash is not a special regex character and not a regex delimiter (these do not exist in C# regex). Youl also need to use a verbatim string literal (i.e. `@"pattern"`) form when converting a JS regex literal to C# pattern.

So, use

```cs
string PoBoxRegex = @"(?i)^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. /\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ .]? ?(o|0)[-. /\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)";
```

The `(?i)` is an inline case insensitive flag.