# Prevent PO Box in form

Tags: forms, validation, bigcommerce

I'm looking for a solution to prevent PO Boxes from being entered into the shipping details on a Big Commerce store, so I'm limited to using JavaScript. I've searched and found some solutions people posted but can't seem to to get any to work correctly.

There is a tutorial someone posted on the BC forums, but it seems rather long for simple validation and even though I got it to work, it us still kinda buggy and doesn't always work. http://forum.bigcommerce.com/f33/how-to-protect-against-po-boxes-in-the-shipping-address-7203/

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't clean input using JavaScript alone. Client-side validation can be circumvented.

Comment: I understand that but still want to try and limit PO Box input as much as possible. There is no access to PHP in Big Commerce so JS is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
[Jquery PO BOX validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666599/jquery-po-box-validation)

In the case of a BC store, assuming the address1 field is still named default as FormField[2][8] or something...

Or maybe assigning the overriding the submit button to preventDefault if the address field as PO box.

```
$('input[name=FormField[2][8]]').each(function() {
    var pattern = new RegExp('[PO.]*\\s?B(ox)?.*\\d+', 'i');
    if ($(this).val().match(pattern)) {
        //do something here
    }
});
```